# ASP.NET MVC display foreign key

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm in ASP.NET using MVC scaffolding. I have a table that has a foreign key in which it has a foreign key I wish to display too. It gets a little confusing.

I have a device table that is linked to a ManufacturerModel table by a foreign key of ManufacturerModelID. The ManufacturerModel table is comprised of the primary key of ManufacurerModelID, a foreign key of ManufacturerID (from a Manufacturer table) and just a Model field. In my device Index screen I would like to display the Device's Manufacturer (from the Manufacturer table) and Model. Currently it will display the model correctly however when I try to add the manufacturer I received the entire ManufacturerModel record including column headers.

In the Device Controller ActionResult for Index() I have the following:

```
var devices = db.Devices.Include(d => d.DeviceType).Include(d => d.ManufacturerModel);
return View(devices.ToList());
```

In my Device Index I have the following for Manufacturer and Model

```
 <th>
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ManufacturerModel.ManufacturerID)
 </th>
 <th>
     @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ManufacturerModel.Model)
 </th>
```

Comment: are you using entity framworke and database first approach?

Comment: Yes I am using both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of you tables relations. your Device doesn't have direct relation to ManufacturerModel. Your relation is based on: devices > DeviceType > ManufacturerModel. 
Try

> var devices = db.Devices.Include(d => d.DeviceType).Include(d => d.DeviceType.ManufacturerModel);

Comment: It does not allow me to add 'd.DeviceType.ManufacturerModel' as it is not a choice under DeviceType. They are two different tables. If I add 'd.ManufacturerModel.Manufacturer' I received an error on my 'return View(devices.ToList());'

Comment: It is just a sample. you should have access to your ManufacturerModel table via devicetype table. just check the object names under devicetype.

Answer (score 1):

So, If I understood correctly, you have

Device -[ManufacturerModel]-> ManufacturerModel -[ManufacturerID]-> Manufacturer

If this is the case, and the foreign keys are correctly defined, you have a class in your model called `Device` which has a property called `ManufacturerModel` which has a property called `Manufacturer` which contains properties related to the columns of the Manufacturer table. I will asume that you have a `Name` property and column respectively and you want to display something like

```
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ManufacturerModel.Manufacturer.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ManufacturerModel.Model)
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>@model.ManufacturerModel.Manufacturer.Name</td>
    <td>@model.ManufacturerModel.Model</td>
<tr>
```

then, when creating the query, you will have to also include (join) the `Manufacturer`table like

```
var devices = db.Devices
    .Include(d => d.DeviceType)
    .Include(d => d.ManufacturerModel)
    .Include(d => d.ManufacturerModel.Manufacturer)
```